# Is there a way to remove points hover animation duration?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I'm currently working on a project including Chart.JS and I pretty much removed points appearances when they're not hovered ; when they are, I just want a point to spawn on them without delay so that the user could slide his mouse up and down the graph to see the different datas.

```
 elements : {
                    point : {
                        borderWidth: 0,
                        radius : 0,
                        backgroundColor : 'rgba(0,0,0,0)'
                    }
```

This is what I'm using to make the points disappear at the moment

I've tried to reach the property by going with

```
point : {
   animation : {
       duration : 0
               }
      }
```

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try add to dataset for point

```
datasets: [{
  animation: false,
  data: [1,2,3,5,4],
}]
```

Comment: Your answer does work but it also removes the animation when you reset zoom which bothers me a bit. Is there a way to target only points animation ?

Comment: you need to remove animation for tooltips? Sorry for wrong answer

Comment: No I only need to remove the points animation (i.e when you hover your points and they take something like 200ms to grow)